# How to dynamically add Date in a form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this form code to dynamically add rows. How can I add a date dynamically?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            cell3.appendChild(element2);

        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }

            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD> 1 </TD>
            <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This the code for adding row dynamically

This is the code for calendar

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="calendar_us.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">

<INPUT type="text" name="testinput" /> 
<script language="JavaScript">

    new tcal ({

        // form name

        'formname': 'testform',

        // input name

        'controlname': 'testinput'
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: you can use template feature instead of adding by javascript , and better use jquery

Comment: and you can add date just as you are adding textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a new cell for example,

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell4.innerHTML = new Date();
```

.

```
<TR>
  <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
  <TD> 1 </TD>
  <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
  <TD> <INPUT type="text" name="testinput" /></TD>
</TR>
```

can you explain where to insert the date?

Comment: the date has to be inserted next to cell 3

Comment: add a cell in table and get help from calendar_us.js's manual. if new cell is not possible then create a new element and append it like before u did. give it's name as expected by ur js